# How to set size of text tab in docusign as fixed according to given width

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi, e-signature

```
text_tabs: [{
    label: 'Client Title',
    anchor_string: 'AGREED BY',
    anchor_x_offset: '155',
    anchor_y_offset: '505',
    height: '20',
    width: '120'
}]
```

by this the text field field is expanding automatically by typed chracters.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the maxLength property.

Like so: "maxLength": 100,